# Looping through characters of a string with int values

Tags: python, string, file, dictionary, character

I'm attempting to solve a testcase from the USACO training: "your ride is here". I attempted to assign letters of the alphabet numerical values and multiply each character in a string for a product.

Example:

```
C   O   M   E   T  Q       
3 *  15 *   13 * 5  * 20 * 17  =  994500
```

Unfortunately the product keeps getting messed up.

```
key = {
    'A':1,
    'B':2,
    'C':3,
    'D':4,
    'E':5,
    'F':6,
    'G':7,
    'H':8,
    'I':8,
    'J':10,
    'K':11,
    'L':12,
    'M':13,
    'N':14,
    'O':15,
    'P':16,
    'Q':17,
    'R':18,
    'S':19,
    'T':20,
    'U':21,
    'V':22,
    'W':23,
    'X':24,
    'Y':25,
    'Z':26
}

file = open("testdata.txt", "r")

message = file.readline(2)

for character in message:
    preSignal = key[character]
    s = preSignal*key[character]
    print(s)
```

Comment: You're basically overwriting `s` at each new character -- you're not "carrying" anything forward. Check out Danil's answer below...

Comment: you're actually squaring the value of each letter if you notice in your code and what @blacksite mentions as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding variable `s` every time and save squared `key[character]` to it (which is not right). You need to create a variable for keeping the result. Try this:

```
result = 1

for character in message:
    result *= key[character]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your answer to s before multiplying so your code would be:

```
key = {'A':1,
   'B':2,
   'C':3,
   'D':4,
   'E':5,
   'F':6,
   'G':7,
   'H':8,
   'I':8,
   'J':10,
   'K':11,
   'L':12,
   'M':13,
   'N':14,
   'O':15,
   'P':16,
   'Q':17,
   'R':18,
   'S':19,
   'T':20,
   'U':21,
   'V':22,
   'W':23,
   'X':24,
   'Y':25,
   'Z':26}

infile = open("testdata.txt", "r")

message = infile.readline(2)
s=1
for character in message:

    s = s*key[character]
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem & Solution

Your problem is that you are essentially overwriting the value of `s` each iteration of your loop. You need to create a variable to hold the value of the current result each iteration, and add to that variable

```
result = 1
for character in message:
    result *= key[character] # same as result = result * key[character]
```

### Improvements

Your mapping of letters to numbers can by simplified:

```
key = {chr(number): number - 64 for number in range(65, 91)}
```

Or you could use `string.ascii_letters`:

```
from string import ascii_letters
key = {letter: number for number, letter in enumerate(ascii_letters, 1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = 1

for i in message:
  s *= key[i]
```

Note that an easier way to construct a dictionary of letters and their corresponding values is to do this:

```
import string

key = {a:i+1 for a, i in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, range(26))}
```

For a purely Python3 solution, you can use `itertools.accumulate`:

```
import itertools
import operator
result = list(itertools.accumulate([key[i] for i in message], func=operator.mul))[-1]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
994500
```